# Displaying timezones into JComboBox

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I am trying to make a `JComboBox` where I want to get all the time zones, but nothing is displayed in it. Could any one help me regarding this problem?

Here is my code:

```
public class Window extends JFrame {
    private static final String DATE_FORMAT = "dd-M-yyyy hh:mm:ss a";
    public Window() {
        super("Genesys");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        setSize(600, 470);
        setVisible(true);
        setLayout(null);
        gradeCombo = new JComboBox < Object > ();
        add(gradeCombo);
        gradeCombo.setBounds(500, 100, 200, 20);
        search.addActionListener(new csearch());
    }
    class csearch implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT);
            Date date = new Date();
            TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getDefault();
            pane.setBounds(10, 530, 760, 40);
            pane1.setBounds(10, 260, 760, 40);
            System.out.println("TimeZone : " + tz.getID() + " - " + tz.getDisplayName());
            System.out.println("TimeZone : " + tz);
            System.out.println("Date (Ro - UTC+02:00) : " + formatter.format(date));
            date10.setText("Current time for Romania");
            date7.setText(String.valueOf("Time Zone : " + tz.getID() + " - " + tz.getDisplayName()));
            date8.setText(String.valueOf("TimeZone : " + tz));
            date9.setText(String.valueOf("Date (Ro - UTC+02:00) : " + formatter.format(date)));
            SimpleDateFormat sdfAmerica = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT);
            SimpleDateFormat sdfParis = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT);
            DateTime dt = new DateTime(date);
            DateTimeZone dtZone = DateTimeZone.forID(country.getText());
            DateTime dtus = dt.withZone(dtZone);
            TimeZone tzInAmerica = dtZone.toTimeZone();
            Date dateInAmerica = dtus.toLocalDateTime().toDate();
            gradeCombo = new JComboBox < Object > (TimeZone.getAvailableIDs());
        }
    }
}
```

Could anyone help me? Why are the time zones not displayed in the combobox?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of instantiating a new JComboBox just set the appropriate model to your existing combo.

```
gradeCombo.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel<Object>( TimeZone.getAvailableIds()));
```